# How to convert this bash prompt to work in zsh terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, prompt

I am trying to get colored text in zsh, and I like the color options given in this bash command `PS1='\[\033[1;36m\]\u\[\033[1;31m\]@\[\033[1;32m\]\h:\[\033[1;35m\]\w\[\033[1;31m\]\$\[\033[0m\]`. However, due to the syntactical differences between zsh and bash, I am unsure as to what the zsh equivalent is.

Is there a tool to convert the bash prompt to a zsh prompt?

Comment: So that's `(user)@(host):(path)$` with some colours, yes?

Comment: @glennjackman Yep, that is exactly what it is doing. I slightly modified tink's answer and achieved desirable results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this resemble what you're after?

```
PS1="%F{cyan}%n%f%F{red}@%f%F{green}%m%f:% %F{magenta}%1~%f %#"
```

Details in `man zshmisc` or `info zsh 'prompt expansion'` :)

Incorporating Stéphane's suggestion and Terdon's comment:

```
PS1="%B%F{cyan}%n%F{red}@%F{green}%m%f%b:% %F{magenta}%1~%f %# "
```

Comment: Nice! The bash one is also using bold for both user and hostname, can that be done in zsh?

Comment: @terdon, `%B` for bold. See `info zsh 'prompt expansion'`.

Comment: You don't need the `%f` (which resets the foreground colour to default) if you're going to change it again with `%F` straight away

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas :)